# How to use mxnet to load grayscale png file?

Tags: mxnet

I want to use mxnet Image API to load grayscale png file.
But Image API became 3channel RGB data.
How to convert from 3channel data to 1channel data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use imdecode function and set flag with 0.
https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/image/image.py#L85

This will require you install opencv and compile mxnet with USE_OPENCV=1

Comment: Can I use  imgdecode with mxnet.image.ImageDetIter with aug_list parameter?